# How to prevent property change event loop in kivy?

Tags: python, events, event-handling, kivy

I have an application acting as a UI for another application through some server. There will be several instances of the UI application. The UI application has a property, `n_property`, representing a parameter of the remote app. When `n_property` is changed through the UI, it is sent to the server – here simulated through `send_value`. The server passes it on to the application to be controlled, it gets validated there, and passed back to the server. The server sends the new value back to the UI (and other connected instances of the UI), simulated here with `receive_value`.

I would like to set `n_property` (and the `Slider` representing it) to the new value *without triggering a new `n_property` event*, because I do not want to enter an infinite loop of changing values, as happens here when the slider is dragged fast enough.

In other frameworks, I'd silence the on change event in `receive_value`, but I haven't found an elegant way to do this in kivy<sup>[1]</sup>.

Here is an example program:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import BoundedNumericProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

class PropApp(App):
    n_property = BoundedNumericProperty(5, min=0, max=10)
    def build(self):
        rw = Builder.load_string("""
GridLayout:
    cols:2
    Label:
        text: "Property Value"
    Label:
        id: prop_label
        text: str(app.n_property)
    Label:
        text: "Control"
    Slider:
        id: prop_slider
        min: 0
        max: 10
        value: app.n_property
""")

        self.bind(n_property=rw.ids.prop_slider.setter('value'))
        rw.ids.prop_slider.bind(value=self.setter('n_property'))

        self.bind(n_property=self.send_value)
        return rw

    def send_value(self, inst, val):
        print self.n_property
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.receive_value(val), .02)
    def receive_value(self, val):
        self.n_property = val

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PropApp().run()
```

### Edit:

According to the docs, event dispatching is stopped once a handler returns `True`, and handlers are called in reverse order of attachment.
So I thought changing `receive_value` to

```
def receive_value(self, val):
    print "Old value: {} new value: {}".format(self.n_property, val)
    def swallow(inst, val):
        print "Got swallowed {}".format(val)
        inst.funbind('n_property', swallow)
        return True
    self.fbind('n_property', swallow)
    self.n_property = val
```

would be a clever way to achieve this, and while yes, I don't seem to be able to end up in an infinite loop, there are still a few 'bounces'.

And it seems that indeed, `EventObservers`, which stores the callbacks, is initialized with `dispatch_reverse=0` in the definition of `Property`, but for events registered with `register_event_type` it's `dispatch_reverse=1`.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> I suppose I could have an attribute `_n_property`, and make `n_property` an `AliasProperty` whose `setter` and `getter` access `_n_property`. But that would not be a general solution for the different subclasses of `Property` (i.e. bounds checking for `BoundedNumericPropery` or `OptionProperty` would have to be separately dealt with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a decorator that stops `on_value` method of a slider from being executed too quickly:

test.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1
GridLayout:
    cols: 1

    ResponseButton:
        text: 'send response from server'
        on_press: self.send_response(int(my_input.text), my_slider)

    TextInput:
        id: my_input
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        text: '50'

    MySlider:
        id: my_slider
```

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from time import time, sleep
from threading import Thread
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class ResponseButton(Button):

    def send_response(self, value, slider):
        slider.receive_response(value)


class delayed:

    def __init__(self, seconds):
        self.seconds = seconds
        self.start = time()
        self.refused = False
        self.function = None
        self.args = None
        self.run_thread()

    def run_thread(self):

        def job():
            while True:
                sleep(self.seconds)
                if self.refused and self._time_ok():
                    self.function(*self.args)
                    self.refused = False

        thread = Thread(target=job)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    def _time_ok(self):
        return time() - self.start > self.seconds

    def __call__(self, function):
        self.function = function

        def decorated(*args):
            self.args = args

            if self._time_ok():
                self.start = time()
                function(*self.args)
            else:
                self.refused = True

        return decorated


class MySlider(Slider):

    _call_server = True

    def receive_response(self, value):
        print '@@@ received from server:', value
        self._call_server = False
        self.value = value

    @delayed(seconds=2)
    def on_value(self, obj, value):
        if self._call_server:
            self.send_value(value)
        else:
            self._call_server = True

    def send_value(self, value):
        print '>>> sent value to server:', value


class Test(App):
    pass


Test().run()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for `on_value`, but I don't see how this would affect callbacks bound to `value`.

Comment: @zeeMonkeez I have updated the code. With this approach, you can keep many client GUIs synchronized without overflowing a server.

Comment: Change `self.args = args` in `decorated` to `self.args = [a.proxy_ref if isinstance(a, Widget) else a for a in args]` in order to create a weak reference to allow for garbage collection.

Comment: I've changed the line, although now it looks somehow ugly.

Comment: Better than leaking memory, though :)

Comment: Actually, do you have a reference for this pattern? Or did you come up with it on the fly?

Comment: @zeeMonkeez This is just a decorator made of a class, I came up with it on the fly.

Comment: Just in case someone reads this in the future: To prevent memory leak it should be sufficient to set `self.args = None` after calling `function(*self.args)`. Makes it look better again ...